No "Search Engine Optimization" section under individual products?
I need to edit titles, meta descriptions, etc. for my products, but there is no "Search Engine Optimization" section under the products.
It shows up under Categories and other pages, but not products.
Catalog>Products>Edit brings me to the page where it should be, but it is not there.
There is a "Meta Information" section, but when I try to edit the Meta Description is won't update and defaults to:
Please help! I either need to be able to edit the Meta Description under the Meta Information, or add in the "Search Engine Optimization" section to the products so that I can edit it there.
Thank you!
Edit: Theme is local argento stripes theme
